# Filtering SQL results due to LEFT JOIN reliant on additional table using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two basic entities, recording and work, I have a table recording_work_tmp that contains recordingid, workid, it only has one row for a particular recording id. Then there is potential another work in l_work_work linked to this work, and then possibly another work linked to this next work and so on upto six levels.

I would like a single row for each record in recording_work_tmp which shows the works at each level (if any). Now I can add  `distinct on(recordingid)`to make sure we don't get more than one recording per row in recording_work_tmp, that is not the problem.

The problem is is only want the works at the other levels to be shown if the link type is 281 but if I change the join to LINK tables to be inner join then it will not return any rows that don't have a valid link for each table.

If I have as LEFT JOIN then it displays value it should not. In the SQL results for **9165022**, **12457013**,  **12803999** should be blank null because they do not have the right link type

If the `l_work_work` table had the `link_type` value then Icould just `left join` on this value and include the link type in this join and records with the wrong link_type would be filtered out at this point. But because its only in the LINK table i cant prevent filtering of wrong records when join to l_work_work table.

How can I write my SQL to return what I require ?

```
SELECT
    t1.recording_id,
    t1.work1_id,
    t4.entity0,
    t5.link_type,
    t6.entity0,
    t7.link_type,
    t8.entity0,
    t9.link_type,
    t10.entity0,
    t11.link_type,
    t12.entity0,
    t13.link_type,
    t14.entity0,
    t15.link_type,
    t16.entity0
    FROM recording_work_tmp t1
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t4
    ON t1.work1_id=t4.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t5
    ON t4.link=t5.id
    and t5.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t6
    ON t4.entity0=t6.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t7
    ON t6.link=t7.id
    AND t7.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t8
    ON t6.entity0=t8.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t9
    ON t8.link=t9.id
    AND  t9.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t10
    ON t8.entity0=t10.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t11
    ON t10.link=t11.id
    AND t11.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t12
    ON t10.entity0=t12.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t13
    ON t12.link=t13.id
    AND  t13.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t14
    ON t12.entity0=t14.entity1
    LEFT JOIN link t15
    ON t14.link=t15.id
    AND t15.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN l_work_work t16
    ON t15.link_type=281
    LEFT JOIN link t17
    ON t16.link=t17.id
    AND t17.link_type=281
    WHERE (t5.link_type=281 OR t5.link_type is null)
    AND   (t7.link_type=281 OR t7.link_type is null)
    AND   (t9.link_type=281 OR t9.link_type is null)
    AND   (t11.link_type=281 OR t11.link_type is null)
    AND   (t13.link_type=281 OR t13.link_type is null)
    AND   (t15.link_type=281 OR t15.link_type is null)
    AND   (t17.link_type=281 OR t17.link_type is null)
    ;
```

returns:

```
 recording_id | work1_id | entity0 | link_type | entity0  | link_type | entity0  | link_type | entity0 | link_type | entity0 | link_type | entity0 | link_type | entity0
--------------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------
      5710625 |  7472941 | 9492475 |       281 |  9165022 |           | 12457013 |       281 |         |           |         |           |         |           |
      5710625 |  7472941 | 9492475 |       281 | 12803999 |           |          |           |         |           |         |           |         |           |
```

Comment: When you include the right-hand table on a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, it filters out the `NULL` conditions, thereby effectively making it an `INNER JOIN`.  (`WHERE` executes *after* the `OUTER JOIN`).  To fix this, you need to include all of the `WHERE` conditions in the appropriate `ON` clauses.

Comment: @Siyual I know that I dont want to filter out rows, its more than  want to filter out column values